# Windows batch file issue setting custom url file icon

Tags: batch-file, url, icons, shortcut

I am creating a url shortcut with a batch script, but for some reason it doesn't set the icon i tell it to set...

**Code:**

```
echo [InternetShortcut]> "C:\winapps\SysNetworkManager.url"
echo URL="C:\winapps\snmres\winstart.bat">> "C:\winapps\SysNetworkManager.url"
echo IconFile="C:\winapps\snmres\snmico.ico">> "C:\winapps\SysNetworkManager.url"
echo IconIndex=0>> "C:\winapps\SysNetworkManager.url"
```

It doesn't set the icon as C:\winapps\snmres\snmico.ico, instead it sets this icon: C:\Windows\system32\url.dll

Comment: The batch file writes the `IconFile` key correctly; I assume you are opening the URL with Internet Explorer, which modifies the file then. There is a problem with the last line: for `cmd`, `=` is a token separator just like _SPACE_, and `0>>` is understood as redirecting _STDIN_ (empty) to the file, so the `IconIndex` key is not written; to work around this, write: `(echo IconIndex=0)>> "C:\winapps\SysNetworkNamager.url"`. I am not sure if it should be the number `1` rather than `0` ( I just checked some random URL files on my system, most of them contained `IconIndex=1`, none contained `0`).

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a temp VBS

```
@echo off

set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"

echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\myshortcut.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath = "D:\myfile.extension" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.IconLocation = "C:\myicon.extension" >> %SCRIPT%

cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%`
```